# Woocommerce - wc_add_notice() not adding to session when nothing in the cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom form that calls a function in function.php when submitted. It will eventually check the fields input and either do something or send back an error message using the `woocommerce wc_add_notice()`, standard stuff.

The problem is, it only seems to add the notice to the session when items have been added to the cart at some point. If I open in an incognito tab and try the form I will get no message. Just to be clear I am using `wc_print_notices()`in my template.

I have printed out the woocommerce session just to confirm and yep its not in there when nothing has been added to the cart. I have stripped the function right back so it should send back an error message when you click submit regardless of anything filled out or not, just to check. Here is the function in question :

```
add_action('wp_ajax_add_transfer', 'process_add_transfer');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_transfer', 'process_add_transfer');
function process_add_transfer() {
     global $woocommerce;
     wc_add_notice( 'This is my custom error', 'error' );
     wp_redirect( get_permalink(125) ); //this is the same page form is on
}
```

[link to page here](http://star2.christianpaton.co.uk/technical-support/product-registration/)

I have searched and searched and have not come across what I am doing incorrectly or why this isn't working, any help appreciatted.

cheers chris

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out! It appears that woocommerce 2.1 > does not set a cookie at until the cart is used, to help with caching or something. Here is a thread on it : https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/4920

Solution for me was to add this to my function :

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_set_cart_cookies',  true );
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: You're a bloody saviour!!!!!
I looked for hours to fix this, then I found this and bingo!

Comment: Glad it helped someone :)

Answer (score 3):

You are just adding the error notices here. It will save these errors in session. Now for showing these error notices, you have to use below function on page you are working or from sending ajax request:

```
wc_print_notices();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response and sorry If i wasn't clear but I have that in my template. The problem seems to be that it is not in the session. But having looked into this a bit further its not whether or not you are logged in but whether or not you have added something to the cart at some point in your session. Is there perhaps something I need to do to start a session without someone adding to the cart?